# Menu button not placed properly on the top right of the page

Tags: css, button, menu, css-position, display

I'm using menu button and i want i placed it on the right of the page
the three lines i used for the menu button is placed in on line when
i used beside each other horizontally i want it to show under each other vertically
I'm trying to make the menu button shown in 3 lines under each other on the right top of the page

```css
.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.menubtn {
  height: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 6px 6px;
  width: 35px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="NuncScript.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <head>
    <a href="#" class="logo">LOGO.</a>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="menubtn"></div>
      <div class="menubtn"></div>
      <div class="menubtn"></div>
    </div>
  </head>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<link>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-link-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: This does not solve your probleme, but remove `<head>` after `<body>` and also `</head>` before `</body>` from the HTML part, because it's invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work fine. Just need some css for the `header` to separate the logo and menu icon to left/right. I recommend using `gap` to separate the `.menu` elements instead of using margin - it would be easier to maintain should you need to adjust in the future.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
}

.menubtn {
  height: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 35px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="NuncScript.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <a href="#" class="logo">LOGO.</a>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="menubtn"></div>
      <div class="menubtn"></div>
      <div class="menubtn"></div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```